# nginx server is not accepting client request and giving status code 324

Tags: cookies, nginx, laravel-4

My website is in Laravel PHP framework, server is nginx. Sometimes it's not giving any response from server in browser. Getting errors like

1. Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
2. Connection Reset error

I checked in the access.log, but no logs for the perticular request is logged. It means when client hit the my URL, he is getting empty response from server. But server is not getting hitted (as per access.log of nginx server).

To access the same URL, client need to clear the browser history(cookie), then he is able to get the data from server which is not the correct solution to follow always.